# Pass values from Servlet to an onload JavaScript function in a JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, onload

I am using the following code in my *Servlet* to set the Attribute *confirmMsg* :

```
req.setAttribute("confirmMsg", "Update Values");
```

This I'm forwarding to the JSP

```
RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("displayDetails.jsp");
rd.forward(req, resp);
```

In my JSP, I need to display the message when the page loads.

```
<body onload = "showConfirmMsg();">

// .....

</body>
```

What should I do in the following function, so as to show the message onload itself?

```
function showConfirmMsg() {

// Code to show the alert box onload

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can do something like:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var msg = "${confirmMsg}";
    // do something with your message :)
});
</script>
```

`<body onload="">` isn't very clean :)

Comment: Is this scenario still recommended now?

Answer (score 0):

Just let JSP/EL print the JS code accordingly so that the browser retrieves valid HTML/JS code.

E.g.

```
<body onload="showConfirmMsg('${confirmMsg}');">
```

with

```
function showConfirmMsg(confirmMsg) {
    // ...
}
```

If you can't guarantee that the `${confirmMsg}` doesn't contain JS-special characters like `'`, newlines, etc then you need to escape it beforehand by for example Apache Commons Lang `StringEscapeUtils#escapeJavaScript()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of calling a function on load, instead use JSP scriplet.

```
<body>
<%=request.getAttribute("confirmMsg")%>
</body>
```